# namespace with variable variable

Tags: namespaces, tcl

I would create a namespace with variable names like :

```tcl
proc show {} {
    puts $fg::varName
    puts $fg::x
}
set p "varName"
namespace eval fg {variable $p FirstValue}
namespace eval fg {variable x "Second variable"}
show
```

This works I think because it is outside a procedure. If I change the code:

```tcl
proc show {} {
    puts $fg::varName
    puts $fg::x
}
# set p ""
proc xx {} {
#   global p
    set p "varName"
    namespace eval fg {variable $p FirstValue}
    namespace eval fg {variable x "Second variable"}
    show
}
xx
```

I get an error i.e. **can't read "p": no such variable**.
It works if I uncomment
`set p ""` and
`global p`
but it seems a little cumbersome.

Comment: The first example is actually an example of the crazy version of Tcl's variable resolution rules, and is the sort of example that was probably in the minds of the people who wrote those rules (for 8.0). It turns out to be a PITA though; use @Chpock's answer in both cases please!

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
namespace eval fg {variable $p FirstValue}
```

The code in brackets evaluated in the specified namespace (global namespace variables are also available there) and $p variable is local for the "xx" procedure.

As a workaround, you may pass the code "pre-evalueted". For example:

```
namespace eval fg [list variable $p FirstValue]
```

Comment: Re “pre-evalueted”, the correct term is _pre-substituted._